# MKMapのピンを押したタイミングで処理を行いたい

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

通常、MapKitを使って地図上にピンを立て、タップするとアノテーションのバルーンが表示されます。
そこで、アノテーションのバルーンが表示されるタイミングで他に何か処理を行いたいのですが、
どこに記述すればよいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

`MKMapViewDelegate`の[`didSelectAnnotationView:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:)です。

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
    didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
}
```